# Windows 7 64bit, Qt 4: glGetVersion returns "1.1.0", nvogl32v.dll gets unloaded

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, qt4, windows-7-x64

**situation**

I'm developing 32bit application that uses Qt 4, and I"m working on Windows 7 64bit.

My program has main non-OpenGL widget, and QGLWidget which is optionally opened by the user.

**problem:**

When I create that `QGLWidget`, `glGetVersion` reports "1.1.0" (my hardware supports OpenGL 4.3.0). As a result many functions I need do not work at all (obviosuly, because they are not available in OpenGL 1). This problem happens "sometimes".

**additional info**

IF I launch program using gDebugger everything works fine, and glGetVersion returns "4.3.0", as expected.
Adding this line:

```
QGLFormat::OpenGLVersionFlags flags = QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags();
```

at the beginning of main() function also fixes the problem.

The application works fine on WinXP 32bit.

I wrote OpenGL subsystem for this app 2..3 years ago and the guys who used it said they had similar problem on virtual machines (Win7 or vista guest), but I don't remember how I dealt with this problem at that time.

**OpenGL initialization**

*OpenGL initialization is performed by Qt 4*, without glew or extra libraries, using QGLWidget.

There's only one QGLWidget in the program. To be precise, there's a class derived from QGLWidget, its initalization looks like this:

```
DisplayWidget::DisplayWidget(QWidget* parent)
    : QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer | QGL::DepthBuffer), parent)
```

**System configuration**:
OS: Windows 7 64bit.
Compiler: MSVC2008 express SP1.
Qt: Qt 4.8.1 (compiled from source with OpenSSL support using MSVC2008).
Windows SDK: Windows Server 2008 and .NET 3.5.
GPU: GeForce 460 GTX

**question**:

What could be causing this problem?

--update--

"magical fix" (OpenGLVersionFlags) has stopped working after full rebuild, and now application constantly initializes software renderer, even when launched using gDebugger.

All other OpenGL applications on my machine work fine and can use shaders.

I use latest drivers.

Any ideas?

--update--

After some testing I found that somehow google chrome and steam client affect all Qt application that use OpenGL.

If I have Google Chrome and Steam open, eventually all programs will stop working properly and will no longer be able to get hardware accelerated OpenGL.

If I close google chrome and keep steam open, every 2nd attempt to launch hardware accelerated program will fail.

If I close both steam and chrome, then every program launch will be successful.

Why could this be happening?

--update--

I've read through debugger output, and found a very interesting thing:

```
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x777f47a5 (ntdll.dll) in vdclient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x05aa9000.
'vdclient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll'
```

Basically, when loading nvoglv32.dll, "something" crahses somewhere (debugger doesn't react to this event, byt the way), and system decides to unload nvoglv32.dll. Judging by its name it is nvidia system/driver component, and without this component there can be no hardware acceleration.

When opengl works properly, this part of log looks like this:

```
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll'
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1744) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1740) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'vdclient.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1748) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x174c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'vdclient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
```

Ideas?

Comment: "*This problem happens "sometimes".*" What does *that* mean? Can you nail down something particular that causes it? What are your pixel format parameters?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sometimes when I start app, it reports gl version 4.3.0. However, in most cases when I start it normally (and without mentioned "magical QGLFormat fix"), gl version reports "1.1.0".

Comment: GPU driver version? Did you try to reinstall the drivers? I suggest you fetch the latest release from NVidia and install that to rule out any driver bugs.

Comment: @datenwolf: Latest drivers - "320.18". Haven't tried reinstalling, because the OS has been installed from scratch recently (less than two weeks ago). I somehow suspect it is Qt 4 bug, not a driver bug, but I have no proof. Is it possible to create OpenGL 1.1.0-only context "by accident" on windows platform? I think that windows by default provides some kind of OpenGL emulation, which is rather limited and OpenGL 1.1.0 only. However, I have no idea what you would need to do to get that one instead of hardware-accelerated OpenGL.

Comment: @SigTerm: Requesting a PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP pixelformat will put you into OpenGL-1.1 mode reliably. Some other PFD configurations are also prone for OpenGL version dropdown as well. But I doubt that this is your problem right now.

Comment: @datenwolf: a dangling pointer or uninitialized variable could, in theory, modify PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR in such way that it would trigger version dropdown. I'm not seeing graphical problems anywhere else, that's why I don't think this is driver's problem. Because app behaves differently under gDebugger, it could be something like that....

Comment: Try using build:release to see what you get.

Comment: Have you tried to put this line `QGLFormat::OpenGLVersionFlags flags = QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags();` after `mainWindow.show();` so the OpenGL context is initialized before querying version flags?

Comment: @user2448027: It will tell that I"m using "OpenGL 1.0". Basically, because of unknown reason program falls back to software rendering. Only THIS program. When this happens, I get certain graphic artifacts, so it is hard to miss.

Comment: @SigTerm Does the same thing happen if you run another program that uses Qt and OpenGL (if you for example create a small test program and run it)?

Comment: @user2448027: It seems that having google chrome open somehow affects Qt+OpenGL programs. If I have chrome/steam open OpenGL+Qt programs eventually stop working and every attempt to get hardware-accelerated OpenGL will fail. If I close it, eventually they start to work properly. :-\

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) Experiment with another browser or other applications that may mess about with OpenGL contexts 2) Retag to include google-chrome and/or steam.

Comment: @Styne666: There's 5 tag limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I give up.

I'll mark it as a driver bug or Google Chrome incompatibility.

I'm gonna add this quirk|problem to project's readme and ensure that app works fine(i.e. doesn't display artifacts) even if OpenGL is emulated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the OpenGL version using QGLFormat.setVersion + QGLFormat.setProfile ?

```
QGLFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion( 3, 2 );
glFormat.setProfile( QGLFormat::CoreProfile );
glFormat.setSampleBuffers( true );

QGLWidget w( glFormat );
```

Another potential problem. Your `glGetVersion` should be called be after the OpenGL context has been initialized in the `QGLWidget.initializeGL()` method.

Comment: Explicitly requesting version 1.5 (That's all I need) does not fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL 3.0 and higher has a deprecation model for legacy features. In old OpenGL versions, the new version was a superset of the old version. I.e. if you wanted OpenGL 1.5 context and got OpenGL 2.0 context, that was fine. Once the possibility of removing old functionality came into being, that is no longer viable. Extension `WGL_ARB_create_context` was made:  it exposes a new function to replace `wglCreateContext`. Much like `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`, it adds an extensibility mechanism to the system that makes it possible to extend the options for context creation. It it impossible to create OpenGL 3.2+ Core Profile context without using this function.

Here is the official up-to-date documentation on how to create an OpenGL context: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)

Comment: No offense, but this is not relevant to the problem. Because same program without any changes either intializes successfully and gets OPenGL 4+ hardware-accelerated context, or fails to initailize properly and gets OpenGL 1.0 context that is emulated by software.

Comment: This could be application/driver specific behavior.

Comment: This behavior is not documented anywhere. So it is a bug, that happens *somewhere*. I'd like to know what causes it and how to reliably bypass/avoid it. That is all.